# How to get data using header name ranges in Excel in case columns are dynamic?

Tags: excel, vba, header, range

I have here a simple form that matches data when ID is entered. It works fine. However, these columns are dynamic/interchangeable. What I would like to do is set the `foundcell variable range` *from column numbers to header names* so whenever the columns are interchanged, ID still has matching intact data after update.

Image of Sheet1 Data

[image: sheet1]

Text Data

```
ID  Description 1   Description 2   Description 3   Description 4
1       Abc             123             Red             Yes
2       Def             456             Blue            Yes
3       Ghi             789             Orange          Yes
4       Jkl             0               Yellow          No
```

So below is a sample matching data for ID 2.

[image: form image]

VBA Excel Code

```
Private Sub id_Change()
Dim id As Variant, rowcount As Integer, foundcell As Range
id = Me.id.value
    rowcount = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & rowcount)
        Set foundcell = .Find(what:=id, LookIn:=xlValues)
          If Not foundcell Is Nothing Then                
                desc1.value = .Cells(foundcell.row, 2) 'I would like to name this as Description 1
                desc2.value = .Cells(foundcell.row, 3) 'I would like to name this as Description 2
                desc3.value = .Cells(foundcell.row, 4) 'I would like to name this as Description 3
                desc4.value = .Cells(foundcell.row, 5) 'I would like to name this as Description 4
            Else
                 desc1.value = ""
                 desc2.value = ""
                 desc3.value = ""
                 desc4.value = ""
            End If
        End With
End Sub
```

Please advise. Thank you..

Comment: use `Application.Match("Description 1",.Range("A1:F1"),0)` in place of the `2` and do adjust for the others.

Comment: @ScottCraner yes, let me try, be right back

Comment: To clarify, when you say "dynamic", is it just the order (column number) that can change? Are the headings ("Description 1" etc.) always the same and are they always four / fixed number?

Comment: @Ratler yes, just the order of the column can change, yes they are always 4, yes headings are always the same

Comment: @ScottCraner this actually worked. but i am quite worried about the `.Range("A1:F1"),0)`, what if the range is beyond letter Z.

Comment: You can always do `Application.Match("Description 1",.Range("A1:ZZ1"),0)`

Comment: @ScottCraner please, put this as an answer so i can accept it. TY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: switched back to Find() for matching the row....

You could do something like this, using a Dictionary:

```
Private Sub id_Change()
    Dim id As Variant, headers As Object, ws As Worksheet, f As range
    id = Me.id.Value
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set headers = AllHeaders(ws, 1) 'get column headers from first row
    Set f = ws.Columns(headers("ID")).Find(id, Lookat:=xlWhole, _
                                             Lookin:=xlValues)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        With f.EntireRow
            desc1.Value = .Cells(headers("Description 1"))
            desc2.Value = .Cells(headers("Description 2"))
            desc3.Value = .Cells(headers("Description 3"))
            desc4.Value = .Cells(headers("Description 4"))
        End With
    Else
        desc1.Value = ""
        desc2.Value = ""
        desc3.Value = ""
        desc4.Value = ""
    End If
End Sub

'Return a Dictionary mapping all headers on row `rw` of sheet `ws`
'   to their column positions.  Assumes all headers are unique.
Function AllHeaders(ws As Worksheet, rw As Long) As Object
    Dim dict As Object, v As String, c As Range
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    dict.comparemode = 1 'vbTextCompare: case-insensitive
    For Each c In ws.Range(ws.Cells(rw, 1), ws.Cells(rw, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Cells
        v = c.Value
        If Len(v) > 0 Then dict.Add v, c.Column 'map headers to column number
    Next c
    Set AllHeaders = dict
End Function
```

Comment: sorry, i pressed something in the keyboard while i pasted the code. the undefined error is now gone. but when entering a number in the text field, all other fields are blank

Comment: If your Id's are numeric then maybe try `id = CLng(Me.id.Value)`

Comment: awesome it is.....